# Combining multiple CSV files with case sensitive column names with Python

Tags: python, dataframe, concatenation, case-sensitive

I have multiple files in a folder with same column details. However for some of the files column name is in lower case, while for the rest column name is in upper case.

I'm using the below code to concat them in one file

```
path = r'folder'
file = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, 'Add', "*.csv"))
data = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f, sep=',', encoding='latin-1') for f in file), ignore_index=True, sort=True)
data['Period'] = '202007' #Period Column is required as string
```

Individual files has 40 columns, but when I'm adding all the files through 'pd.concat' I'm getting 81 columns (40 in upper case + 40 in lower case + 1 created column).

I need final output as 41 columns - 40 columns either in upper/lower case + 1 created column

Thanks to Sid for the concat help.

Update (data types): I have different data types (int, float, object) in my data.

Answer (score 1):

Try to convert your column names all to lowercase before concatenating your dataframes:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.lower()
```

You should also unify your data types. For this, have a look on [astype](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html)

Comment: I tried to break down the code I'm using in like below, but it didn’t help.

'Folder = (pd.read_csv(f, sep=',', encoding='latin-1') for f in ASTI)'         
'Folder.columns = Folder.columns.str.upper()'           
'data = pd.concat(Folder, ignore_index=True, sort=True)'

The error message received is “AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'columns'. 
Any specific way to define the “df”.    Also I have both numeric and text columns, so unifying the data may not be possible.

Comment: you are assigning a generator expression to your variable "Folder", but you have to do the renaming of the columns for each dataframe individually. so store the dataframe in a list instead and then something like "for df in Folder: df.columns = df.columns.str.upper()" should be able to solve your problem.

Comment: Yupp, just restructured the if condition to consider the csv read and it worked.

"for csvfile in ASTI:
    df = pd.read_csv(csvfile)
    df.columns = map(str.upper, df.columns)"